# Why can't exit() terminate the program immediately while in the readlines loop?

Tags: python, ipython, readlines

Part of my program is:

```
f = open('test.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    print 'test'
    exit()
```

Why can't I exit the program immediately when first meet the exit? Instead, my program will exit while the loop has finished.

### EDIT

It happened in the interactive mode:

```
In [1]: f = open('test.txt', 'r')

In [2]: for line in f.readlines():
   ...:     print 'test'
   ...:     exit()
   ...:     
test
test
test
test
test
test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exit` in IPython is not the same function as `exit` in Python.
In IPython, `exit` is an instance of `IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall`:

```
In [6]: exit?
Type:       ExitAutocall
String Form:<IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall object at 0x9f4c02c>
File:       /data1/unutbu/.virtualenvs/arthur/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.14.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/autocall.py
Definition: exit(self)
Docstring:
An autocallable object which will be added to the user namespace so that
exit, exit(), quit or quit() are all valid ways to close the shell.
Call def:   exit(self)

In [7]: type(exit)
Out[7]: IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall
```

It's definition looks like this:

```
class ExitAutocall(IPyAutocall):
    """An autocallable object which will be added to the user namespace so that
    exit, exit(), quit or quit() are all valid ways to close the shell."""
    rewrite = False

    def __call__(self):
        self._ip.ask_exit()
```

The `self._ip.ask_exit()` call runs this method:

```
def ask_exit(self):
    """ Ask the shell to exit. Can be overiden and used as a callback. """
    self.exit_now = True
```

So it really does not exit IPython, it just sets a flag to exit when control returns to the IPython prompt.

Answer (score 3):

It works just fine for me:

```
sandbox $ wc -l test.tex
       9 test.tex
sandbox $ python test.py | wc -l
       1
```

So this probably isn't your *actual* code.

There's a few reasons that might make you think you're not exiting when you want to however.  `file.readlines()` stores all of the lines in a list.  Further `file.read*` will act like you've hit the end of the file (because you have!).

To iterate over a file line by line, use the idiom:

```
for line in f:
    do_something_with(line)
```

Alternatively, use `sys.exit`.  The "builtin" `exit` function is really only meant to be [used interactively](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#exit).  (In fact, it's not a "builtin" at all according to the documentation, so you could definitely get funny behavior from it using different python implementations).